# How to send a friend request through the PHP Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a website where I'd like to allow a user to send a Facebook friend request to another through the website. I have the Facebook account information for both. Is this possible? I know it was in the old version of the GRAPH API and also using FBML, both of which are outdated now.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friendrequests#publish

> You can't publish using this edge. The Friends Dialog should be used if you want to integrate the ability to add someone as a friend in your app.

The Friend Dialog was removed with v2.0, so there is no way anymore.